# Linux Wifi gone after restart and not searching wifi networks

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I am new to kali linux and after i installed linux there was no wifi I installed drivers using (make unload) and (make load commands) but there was no wifi to connect it was saying no network and whenever i restart my computer there was no wifi and I do not know if this is correct way to install or not.
After restart iwconfig is giving only eth0 and lo with no wireless extension.
I used `apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi` but it is giving

```
firmware-iwlwifi is already the newest version (20170823-1)
0 upgraded 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

Please give me fix so that my wifi will not get removed after restart and wifi will search and connect to networks.

`lspci` and `lsusb` show

```
# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
```

and

```
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6473 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: iwlwifi is the wrong firmware (driver). Look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvMlxdIUTPs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is solved my apt-get update was not working and giving error at that time i just solved this by using these command one by one

```
# sudo -i
# touch /etc/apt/sources.list
# chmod 644 /etc/apt/sources.list
# echo "deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 7D8D0BF6
```

After that my apt-get update was working and then i used these commands and downloaded the driver and installed

```
# git clone https://github.com/mehedishakeel/BroadcomInstaller2017.git
```

Then i copied the downloaded file on desktop and used these commands

```
# cd ~/Desktop/BroadcomInstaller2017/
# ls
# cat Readme.md
# chmod +x Broadcom.sh
# ./Broadcom.sh
```

Then it gives 3 options select 1 option and it will install wifi drivers of Broadcom.

I don't know if this commands will work for others or not but it worked for me alternatively there is another command.

```
# apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux- headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

I hope that this command will work for others and now this question is closed.